# Find out if the next integer in a stack array is the same

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

So I am trying to implement this method to know if an integer occurs twice consecutively in my stack array. This integer is taken as a parameter and I want to know if it happens twice consecutively. Unfortunately, my method always returns false, do you know why?

```
template<class T>
bool stack<T>::isConsecutive( const T & data ) const{
    bool flag=false;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < _top; i++) {
        if(data==elements[i] && elements[i]==elements[i+1]){
            flag=true;
        }
        else {
            flag=false;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: Your flag will be reset to false as you don't break/return when you find an instance of consecutive numbers, also `i < _top` should probably be `i < _top - 1` , at the moment assuming `_top` is the size of the stack, ub is invoked.

Comment: I added the return statement and it worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
template<class T>
bool stack<T>::isConsecutive( const T & data ) const{
bool flag=false;

for (size_t i = 0; i < _top-1; i++) {
    if(data==elements[i] && elements[i]==elements[i+1]){
        return true;
    }
  }
 return flag;
 }
```

this will work i guess .

Comment: you can get rid of `flag` as it is always `false`